# Where the ca path on OSX install k8s with docker-desktop

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I know on Linux the path is `/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem`.

I installed k8s 1.22.5 on osx to use docker-desktop，and it can run. But I want to know where is the ca path on osx.
[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue? Do you receive any errors, etc?

Comment: It can run well , but I just want to get the ca and try to generate the kubctl config